# Jumping square. thread. Prevent from jumping several times

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, thread-safety

I am trying to implement a jumping square. The square should not be able to jump several times like in flappy bird but have to return on its baseYPosition or - to be implemented later - on a platform(simple [GeometryDash](https://youtu.be/4TkrQ5SCnvU?t=9) clone for a school project).

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Square extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int threadDelay = 40;
    public int squareYPosition = 400,squareXPosition = 400, baseYPosition = 400;
    public int jumpyness = 40, gravity=3, ySpeed, counter = 0;
    public boolean isJumping;



    public Square(){
        Timer t = new Timer(threadDelay, this);
        t.start();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(squareXPosition, squareYPosition, 40, 40);
    }

    public void jump(){
        ySpeed = jumpyness;

        System.out.println("squareYPosition before while: "+squareYPosition);
        System.out.println("jumping before?"+isJumping);

        if(!isJumping){
            isJumping = true;
            System.out.println("was not jumping before?"+isJumping);
            new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    while(isJumping && (ySpeed!=0 || squareYPosition < baseYPosition)){
                        if(squareYPosition < 0){
                            ySpeed=-1;
                            squareYPosition = 0 ;

                        }
                        System.out.println("squareYPosition: "+squareYPosition+" . ySpeed: "+ySpeed);
                        if(squareYPosition-ySpeed > baseYPosition && counter>(jumpyness/gravity)){
                            squareYPosition = baseYPosition;
                            ySpeed = 0;
                            counter = 0;
                            isJumping = false;
                            System.out.println("set ySpeed to 0");
                        }
                        else{
                            squareYPosition = squareYPosition - ySpeed;
                            ySpeed = ySpeed - gravity;
                            counter++;

                        }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(threadDelay);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                    }


                }

            }.start();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();

    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:         
            this.jump();
            break;
        case 38:
            this.jump();
            break;


        }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

The Square class is instantiated in and added to a JFrame.

MainFrame.java

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Square square;

    public MainFrame(String text, GraphicsDevice device, DisplayMode displayMode){
        setTitle(text);
        setUndecorated(true);


        square = new Square();      
        add(square);


        //pack();
        setVisible(true);       
        device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
        device.setDisplayMode(displayMode);


        repaint();
        addKeyListener(square);
    }
}
```

PeterTest.java

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class PeterTest {
    static long revalidateDelay = 30;

    static final int ELEMENTESTART = 3; // Elemente +1 f�r L�cken/abstand oben/unten

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GraphicsEnvironment enivronment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice device = enivronment.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        DisplayMode[] ds = device.getDisplayModes();

        //The following is necessary because Unix and Windows have reversed orders in DisplayMode
        int highestResolutionIndex = getHighestResolutionIndex(ds);
        DisplayMode displayMode = new DisplayMode(ds[highestResolutionIndex].getWidth(), ds[highestResolutionIndex].getHeight(), ds[highestResolutionIndex].getBitDepth(), ds[highestResolutionIndex].getRefreshRate());

        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame("Test", device, displayMode);
//      

    }

    public static int getHighestResolutionIndex(DisplayMode[] ds){
        long pixels = ds[ds.length-1].getWidth() * ds[ds.length-1].getHeight();
        int highestResolutionIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<ds.length; i++){
            long newpixels = ds[i].getWidth() * ds[i].getHeight();
            if(newpixels>=pixels){
                highestResolutionIndex = i;
                pixels = newpixels;             
            }
        }
        return highestResolutionIndex;
    }



}
```

The boolean isJumping should prevent the thread to be opened while there is another thread for the jumping, but holding the space key will let the square hit the top of the frame. Even locking the boolean will not work for me. I have no idea how to fix this :( 
Please help me :'(

Comment: You might take into consideration that most readers will have zero knowledge of the GeometryDash you are referring to, and your code does not provide a self contained runnable example to a least verify the current state easily. Improving the question to address these shortcommings would improve your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations! I added the mentioned information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem myself. It hurts. The problem was setting the ySpeed to jumpyness in the first line of jump() and not in the thread before the while.